# minimizing latency between two Azure VMs in the same region?

Tags: azure

I wonder - what is the best way to minimize latency between two VMs in Azure in the same region, VNET and Resource Group?

Comment: Wow. Not a speck of detail in your question. I'm not sure what type of answer you're expecting but I wouldn't be hopeful for a detailed or insightful response.

Comment: Well, not sure what to add there. I am trying to figure out what is the best way to make the network latency between two VMs in Azure low :) The same region, the same VNET and RG for simplicity. Unless there is nothing you can tweak on the platform level and "it is what it is" :)

Comment: 1. What is the latency? 2. Details about the VM's, such as size, configuration, OS, applications, etc. 3. Are you dealing with overall/general latency or application specific latency? 4. What region? The more details you can provide the more info we'll have to try to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the best way to minimize latency between two VMs in Azure in
>   the same region, VNET and Resource Group?

Yes, in the same Vnet will have the low latency.

By the way, different vm sizes have different bandwidth.

Here a blog post we look at some network bandwidth tests for a variety of Azure VM sizes.

VMs in the same Vnet:

[image]

Here is the result:
[image]

More information, please refer to this [blog](https://azure-in-action.blog/2017/01/01/azure-vm-network-bandwidth-tests/).